# How do I get around the permission denied message in git bash?

Tags: bash, git

I just started using git bash today for an Udacity class.

- I've created a file called `test.txt` and I've saved it to my desktop.
- I've created a folder called `turnitup` in my desktop.
- I then moved `text.txt` to the `turnitup` folder.

I try to move test.txt back to the desktop by using `mv test.txt /desktop` while I'm in the path `~/desktop/turnitup`.

Whenever I do this, I get an error message:

```
mv: cannot move 'test.txt' to '/desktop' : Permission denied".
```

How do I get around this so that I can move the `test.txt` file back to the desktop location where it was originally created?

Comment: Nothing to do with Git, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Git for Windows bash session `/` refers to Git installation folder.

So a `mv test.txt /desktop` is interpreted as rename `test.txt` as `desktop` and put it in `/`.

But `/` is generally off-limit.

If you are already in  `/c/Users/<user>/Desktop/turnitup`, a simple `mv test.txt ..` is enough.